# Map method is only showing one item from the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios, tsx

I have created a React App and I am using .Net Core in the backend, the list of  data from backend is successfully received, but in react while using Map it only shows one item from the list.I ma using MObX for state management.

My Code is :

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { RootStoreContext } from '../../app/stores/rootStore';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { Segment, Item, Icon, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const BookList: React.FC = () => {
    const rootStore = useContext(RootStoreContext);
    const { loadBooks, getAvailableBooks } = rootStore.bookStore;

    useEffect(() => {
        loadBooks();
    }, [loadBooks]);

    return (
        <div>
            {getAvailableBooks.map(books => (
                <Segment.Group key={books.bookName}>
                    <Segment>
                        <Item.Group>
                            <Item>
                                <Item.Image size='tiny' circular src='/assets/user.png' />
                                <Item.Content>
                                    <Item.Header as='a'>{books.bookName}</Item.Header>
                                </Item.Content>
                            </Item>
                        </Item.Group>
                    </Segment>
</Segment.Group>
 ))}

</div>
    )
}

export default observer(BookList);
```

My BookStore is :

```
import { observable, action, computed, runInAction } from "mobx";
import agent from "../api/agent";
import { RootStore } from "./rootStore";
import { IBooks } from "../models/books";

export default class BookStore {
  rootStore: RootStore;
  constructor(rootStore: RootStore) {
    this.rootStore = rootStore;
  }

  @observable bookRegistry = new Map();
  @observable book: IBooks | null = null;
  @observable loadingInitial = false;

  @computed get getAvailableBooks() {
    return Array.from(this.bookRegistry.values());
  }

  @action loadBooks = async () => {
    this.loadingInitial = true;
    try {
      const books = await agent.Books.list();
      runInAction("loading books", () => {
        books.forEach((books) => {
          books.issuedOn = new Date(books.issuedOn);
          this.bookRegistry.set(books.id, books);
        });
        this.loadingInitial = false;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      runInAction("load books error", () => {
        this.loadingInitial = false;
      });
    }
  };
}
```

and API is called from agent.ts

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { history } from "../..";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { IBooks } from "../models/books";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://localhost:44396/api";

const requests = {
  get: (url: string) => axios.get(url).then(sleep(1000)).then(responseBody),
  post: (url: string, body: {}) =>
    axios.post(url, body).then(sleep(1000)).then(responseBody),
  put: (url: string, body: {}) =>
    axios.put(url, body).then(sleep(1000)).then(responseBody),
  del: (url: string) => axios.delete(url).then(sleep(1000)).then(responseBody),
};

const Books = {
  list: (): Promise<IBooks[]> => requests.get("/Book/GetBookList"),
};


export default {
  User
};
```

```
export interface IBooks {
  id: number;
  bookname: string;
  issuedOn: Date;
  isReturned: boolean;
  isRequested: boolean;
  isAvailable: boolean;
  isTaken: boolean;
  name: string;
}
```

The response from API
[image]

Comment: This is not the issue but avoid naming the callback's parameter name same as the array `books.forEach((books) => {` It will work, but it's confusing. Something like a singular `book` as the parameter name is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the screenshot of your API response, it seems that each "book" object does not have an `id` property. This might explain why you only see one element rendered, because in your `loadBooks` action, each time you try to do `this.bookRegistry.set(books.id, books)`, you're using `undefined` as the key, and then on the next iteration you overwrite the value stored at that key.

Comment: Good catch. If they add `index` to `books.forEach((books)` above, they could use that as a key instead. Also, rename the instance variable inside the the `forEach` to `book`